# NERDTree don't create window on open when file is not saved

Tags: vim, vimrc

Is there a way to convince NERDTree to always hide editor window? Because when I open file and I have unsaved changes in previous one, NERDTree will open new window, so it is opened in split. I don't want that. Only solution for me now is to save every time I want change file through NERDTree or manually execute :hide.

Comment: Did you try adding `set hidden` to your `.vimrc`?